# Visual Studio 2017 .NET Framework 4.5.2

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've developed a program with VB.net and the Application settings target the .NET Framework 4.5.2.

I have to write a requirement list for running the program. Should I write: it needs at least .NET Framework 4.5.2 in order to run it? And I'm curious, do I see it correctly that you need to have at least a Windows Vista Service Pack 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set .NET Framework 4.5.2 for your apps, then the "System Requirements" section stated by Microsoft applies to you too,

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42642

> **System Requirements**
>
> **Supported Operating System**
>
> Windows 7 Service Pack
> 1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server
> 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2,
> Windows Vista Service Pack 2
>
> **Hardware Requirements:**
>
> - 1 GHz or faster
>   processor
> - 512 MB of RAM
> - 4.5 GB of available hard disk space (x86)
> - 4.5 GB of available hard disk space (x64)